# OpenSSH 5.9p1 on Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: ubuntu, security, ssh, package-management, deb

I want to build a deb package with the latest version of openssh from source. Then I want to install it on my machine. 
I am running:

```
Linux Ubuntu-1110-oneiric-64-minimal 3.0.0-12-server #20-Ubuntu SMP Fri Oct 7 16:36:30 UTC 2011 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

To achieve my goal I do:

```
wget ftp://ftp.openbsd.com/pub/OpenBSD/OpenSSH/portable/openssh-5.9p1.tar.gz
wget ftp://ftp.openbsd.com/pub/OpenBSD/OpenSSH/portable/openssh-5.9p1.tar.gz.asc
gpg openssh-5.9p1.tar.gz.asc 
apt-get build-dep openssh-server openssh-client
apt-get source openssh-server
cd openssh-5.8p1/
uupdate -v 5.9p1 /root/packages/openssh/openssh-5.9p1.tar.gz
cd ../openssh-5.9p1
dpkg-buildpackage -us -uc -nc
```

But I get an error:

```
make[1]: Entering directory `/root/packages/openssh/openssh-5.9p1'
rm -f debian/tmp/etc/ssh/sshd_config
dh_install -Nopenssh-client-udeb -Nopenssh-server-udeb --fail-missing
cp: cannot stat `debian/tmp/usr/bin/ssh-vulnkey': No such file or directory
dh_install: cp -a debian/tmp/usr/bin/ssh-vulnkey debian/openssh-client//usr/bin/     returned exit code 1
make[1]: *** [override_dh_install] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/root/packages/openssh/openssh-5.9p1'
make: *** [binary] Error 2
dpkg-buildpackage: error: debian/rules binary gave error exit status 2
```

Any ideas what do I do to make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to download the unstable 5.9 *.deb and install it manually.

Answer (score 0):

ssh-vulnkey looks like its part of the openssh-client package.  I'm not that familiar with Ubuntu packaging, but I assume you'd also have to do something like `apt-get source openssh-client` to get that file, since it won't be in the openssh-server source package.

```
$ dpkg -S ssh-vulnkey
openssh-client: /usr/bin/ssh-vulnkey
```